# header can set in localhost but does not work in live server(dot net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to add following header in my application(**vb.net**)

```
Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "deny")
```

it works ok on loacahost nut does not reflect in live server